# sql categorypath of parent categories in join

Tags: sql, join, recursion, parent

i have tried and searched a while, and i dont think there is much missing, but i need help:

I can only modify the query by adding a (left) join becouse its an automatic created query
So its beginning with `SELECT * FROM question q LEFT JOIN ...`

now comes the part (if in php selected) that should connect every question (question has a category id (q.category)) with the category-path:

```
LEFT JOIN (
SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(cn.name SEPARATOR ' >> ') AS categorypath
FROM    (
        SELECT  _id AS id, parent,
                @cl := @cl + 1 AS level
        FROM    (
                SELECT  @r AS _id,
                        (
                        SELECT  @r := parent
                        FROM    categories
                        WHERE   id = _id
                        ) AS parent,
                        @l := @l + 1 AS level
                FROM    (
                        SELECT  @r := q.category,
                                @l := 0,
                                @cl := 0
                        ) vars,
                        categories qct
                WHERE   @r <> 0
                ORDER BY
                        level DESC
                ) qi
        ) cp
LEFT JOIN categories AS cn ON cp.id = cn.id
) ON q.category = ...(dont know)
```

So this the part wich is without the first left join working if i fill a value for the "q.category" in the middle of the query. (for example @r := 8)
But i need it for every question as a joined table...

Thanks

Edit: the used database will be a MySQL-database

Comment: Which DBMS (and version) are you using? With any modern DBMS you should be able to do that with a recursive query (although that would imply changing the basic SELECT as well).

Comment: mysql will be used, changing the whole query wont be possible